# WELD-000072 Managed bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld

I wrote a simple program in java web forms but i am receiving the following error:

> WELD-000072 Managed bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class `BeanPakage.DemoBeans`] with qualifiers [`@Any` `@Default` `@Named`]

Can anyone tell me where this error comes from?

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named("DemoBeans")
@SessionScoped
public class DemoBeans {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can make your bean passivation capable by implementing the Serializable interface:

```
public class DemoBean implements Serializable { ... }
```

Note that there are more requirements for being passivation capable. Refer to the Weld documentation for more information.

Answer (score 22):

The error might remain even though the CDI bean is serializable:

```
WELD-000072 Managed bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable
```

Example class:

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class TransactionMatchController implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Make sure that all **@Interceptors** are seializable as well:

```
@Interceptor
@Transactional
public class TransactionInterceptor implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, serializable `@Interceptors` was the problem for me !

Answer (score 6):

It must be serializable.

See this answer.

https://community.jboss.org/thread/179828

Best,
Anders

Answer (score 6):

Make `DemoBeans` **serialized**

```
@Named("DemoBeans")
@SessionScoped
public class DemoBeans  implements Serializable
{

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also activate passivation behavior of your bean with the annotation:

@Stateful(passivationCapable=true)

In this case you don't need to implement Serializable interface.

Regards.
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

Verify imports

(some times netbeans used others from others libraries)

Example. import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped; change it by import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

Comment: Actually JSF 2.3 deprecates `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` in favour to `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`. Does this mean I have to go through all my view scoped beans and make them serializable? From the `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` javadoc: 
`@deprecated This has been replaced by {@code javax.faces.view.ViewScoped}. The functionality of this corresponding annotation is identical to this one, but it is implemented as a CDI custom scope.`

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000072: Bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class com.marcos.controller.PersonaBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]

---

I solved it, apparently CDI,I did not recognize the bean, I just made it more explicit

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PersonaBean  implements Serializable {
@Inject
private IPersonaService service;
public void registrar() {

    try {
        service.registrar(null);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

the solution for me:

```
@Named ("PersonaBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonaBean  implements Serializable {
@Inject
private IPersonaService service;
public void registrar() {

    try {
        service.registrar(null);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```